# Whitespace error near the end of the output

Tags: c

Given a positive integer n, the following rules will always create a sequence that ends with 1, called the hailstone sequence:

- If n is even, divide it by 2
- If n is odd, multiply it by 3 and add 1 (i.e. 3n +1)
- Continue until n is 1

Write a program that reads an integer as input and prints the hailstone sequence starting with the integer entered. Format the output so that ten integers, each separated by a tab character (\t), are printed per line.

The output format can be achieved as follows:
printf("%d\t", n);

Example, if the input is:

```
25
```

then the output is:

```
25   76   38   19   58   29   88   44   22   11 
34   17   52   26   13   40   20   10   5    16 
8    4    2    1
```

Code used so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int n;
    int count = 0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("%d\t", n, end='\t');
    count++;
    while (n != 1) {
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            n = n / 2;
        }
        else {
            n = 3 * n + 1;
        }
        printf("%d\t", n);
        count++;
        if (count % 10 == 0) {
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Apart from the horrible indentation, I don't see any problems here.

Comment: The compiler tells you what's wrong: https://godbolt.org/z/7fG1s71Pz

Comment: After removing that one syntax error, it looks good: https://godbolt.org/z/EGcnq77z8

Answer (score 2):

`printf("%d\t", n, end='\t');` is a compiler error.  I suspect OP wanted `printf("%d\n", n);`

---

> Whitespace error near the end of the output

> Format the output so that ten integers, each separated by a tab character (\t), are printed per line.

To print a `'\t'` only *between* integers on the same line, do not use `printf("%d\t", n);` which print a tab after *every* integer.  Instead print a separator that becomes a tab after the first integer per line.

```
   const char *sep = "";
   while (n != 1) {
     ...
     printf("%s%d", sep, n);
     sep = "\t";
     count++;
     if (count%10 == 0) {
       sep = "\n";
     }
   }
   printf("\n");
```

Comment: Why use a string for a single `char`?

Comment: @AdrianMole `sep` is not always a single `char` as in `const char *sep = "";`

Comment: `char sep = '\0';` ... `sep = '\t'` ... and `%c` as the format specifier.

Comment: @AdrianMole `char sep = '\0'; printf("%c%d", sep, n);` would print the _null character_ before the integer - which is undesirable.

Comment: Yeah, but a slightly different logic (i.e. using `%d%c`) would sort all that out. Still, I guess it's your preference.

Comment: @AdrianMole IMO, printing the separator after the integer leads to more complex code. I invite you to post such a solution. As I see it, printing the separator is really a function of what happened before and not what might happen next as it is separating the new output from previous.

Answer (score 0):

The only real *error* in your code is in the `printf("%d\t", n, end='\t');` line; in C, there is no such "end specifier" in the arguments to `printf`. (Did you try to 'borrow' this from Python's `print` function?)

Other than that, the [code given by Chux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77098412/10871073) will work well but there is an alternative, using only a single character separator (rather than the pointer to various string literals that Chux uses).  I have also added a couple of other 'minor optimizations' to the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    int count = 1; // Start at 1 to avoid an extra ++ operation
    char sep = '\t';
    scanf("%d", &n);
    while (n != 1) {
        printf("%d%c", n, sep);
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            n = n / 2;
        }
        else {
            n = 3 * n + 1;
        }
        if (++count % 10 == 0) {
            sep = '\n';
        }
        else {
            sep = '\t';
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", n); // The final "1"
    return 0;
}
```